# Area using definite integrals with a straight line

Tags: integration, algebraic-curves

I'm really stuck on this.  Say you have a curve $y = 3x - x^2$ that cuts the x-axis at points $O$ and $A$, and meets the line $y = -3x$ at the point $B$.  How would you find the area of this shaded region?
[image]

I tried integrating between $O$ and $B$, and then I was going to take away the triangle (not shown) with hypotenuse $O$ to $B$.  But this didn't work.  The answer is 36, but I just can't get there.

Comment: Can you please add some more details about what you tried. What did you integrate between $O$ and $B$ would help others understand where you are getting stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First evaluate the x value of $B$.

$$3x-x^2=-3x$$
$$6x-x^2=0$$
$$x(6-x)=0$$
So $B$ is at $x=6$ (and $A$ is at $x=0$)

Construct integral: $\int_0^63x-x^2\space-\space-3x\space dx$

$$\int_0^63x-x^2\space-\space-3x\space dx=\int_0^6 6x-x^2dx$$
$$=\left(3x^2-\frac{x^3}{3}\right)_0^6$$
$$=3\times6^2-\frac{6^3}{3}$$
$$=108-72$$
$$=36$$

Comment: Sorry, just where you put "-3x", do you mean "- -3x" so "+3x" because you want to subtract the area under the line?

Comment: Yeh oops I missed a minus sign. With an area between two curves you want to do top curve take away bottom curve.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

The first step is finding the points of intersection between the two graphs. We do $3x-x^2 = -3x \implies x = 0$ or $x = 6$. Now, in order to be precise, see that $3x-x^2 \geq -3x$ on $[0,6]$.

The question is a little bit tricky since the quadratic is both positive and negative on this interval, thus by subtracting the area under the linear function gives us the full area. Therefore the answer is $\displaystyle \int_{0}^6 (3x-x^2)dx-\int_{0}^6(-3x) = 36$.